# Toda vez que vou dar node acontece um erro

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou programando um BOT para o Discord e não consigo resolver o erro abaixo:

```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)        
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Meu codigo :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client(); 
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const streamOptions = {seek: 0, volume: 1};

const token = 'Njg4NTc1NzE1NzE3MDIxNzUx.Xm2UKA.stJB8VEHvjpfOVsR6qw1NGOceLs';
bot.login(token);

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('estou pronto para ser usado');
});

bot.on('message', msg => {}
    if(msg.author.bot) {
          return;   
    }

    if(msg.content.indexOf("youtube")!==-1 && msg.content.toLowerCase(),startsWith ("?play"))
        let CompleteMessage = msg.content.split('');

        let youtubeLink = CompleteMessage [1];

        if (VoiceChannel == null) {
            console.log('Canal nâo foi encontrado!');
        }

        if (VoiceChannel !== null) {
            console.log('O canal foi encontrado!');

            VoiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => {
                const stream = ytdl(youtubeLink, {filter:'audioonly'});

                const DJ = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions)
                DJ.on('end', end => {
                    VoiceChannel.leave();

                });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
        }
```

Comment: Isso aí acontece quando você você digita apenas `node` ou quando você tentar executar seu código com Node ? Se for o caso, deverá colocar seu código para a gente analisar.

Comment: Falta um pedaço no fim do fonte, uma chave e um parênteses, para fechar bot.on('message', ... se estiver faltando no código real, vai dar erro de sintaxe mesmo.

Comment: Vlw mais... quando fui digitar node deu a seguinte mensagem : Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja algum erro de sintaxe. na seguinte linha:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {}
```

o if e tudo mais tem que ficar dentro das chaves

exemplo:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Referencia: https://discord.js.org/#/